# How do you stop Pydantic from accepting additional attributes in a nested model

Tags: python, pydantic

I find the following Pydantic behaviour surprising.

First I create Item, and then extend it with ItemExtended to include an additional attribute. Now I create ItemContainer which can take a list of Items.

```
from typing import List

from pydantic import BaseModel


class Item(BaseModel):
    thing: int


class ItemExtended(Item):
    extra_thing: int = 456


class ItemContainer(BaseModel):
    items: List[Item]
```

For some reason if I now create an instance of ItemContainer passing in an ItemExtended then rather than converting the ItemExtended to an Item it is simply allowed, along with the unwanted default value.

i.e. this

```
ItemContainer(items=[ItemExtended(thing=123)])
```

becomes

```
ItemContainer(items=[ItemExtended(thing=123, extra_thing=456)])
```

Is there a way to strictly enforce the items type such that this

```
ItemContainer(items=[ItemExtended(thing=123)])
```

becomes

```
ItemContainer(items=[Item(thing=123)])
```

Comment: Do you know about the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)?

Comment: Fair point, I can see that `isinstance(ItemExtended(thing=123), Item)` returns `True` but in the context of strictly enforced data models it feels wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking to do violates how Python thinks about typing. Pydantic is doing something that makes intuitive sense: You're asking it be an `Item`, and it is, in fact, an `Item`.

If you want to be strict about what's provided, create a stricter subclass:

```py
from typing import List

from pydantic import BaseModel


class Item(BaseModel):
    thing: int

class StrictItem(Item):
    pass

class ItemExtended(Item):
    extra_thing: int = 456

class ItemContainer(BaseModel):
    items: List[StrictItem]
```

I think you're asking for automatic conversion, however, which you could create a validator for.